# Angular ngcontent messing up the bootstrap style

Tags: css, angular, angular5

I am working on Angular 5 alongwith bootstrap 4. 
Here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
 <app-home></app-home>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**home.component.html**

```
 <header id="home-section">
  <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="home-inner">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-8 d-none d-lg-block">
                      <p>HELLO</p>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <div class="card bg-primary text-center card-form">
                          <div class="card-body">
                              <h3>Sign Up Today</h3>
                              <p>Please fill out this form to register</p>
                              <form>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Username">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                  </div>
                                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-block">
                              </form>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Angular is adding a style as follows:

```
*[_ngcontent-c1] {
    margin: 0%;
}
```

This style is interfering with my bootstrap container class and there is an extra space on right hand side of the page. I will attach snapshot here:
[image: This screenshot is with the _ngcontent-c1 default style]

In the above image, the container is clearly not in the middle.

Here is the screenshot where I commented out this style in chrome inspect.
[image: Screenshot without _ngcontent-c1 style]

I am not sure why this is happening and how I can fix this. I cannot comment out this ngcontent style as it is part of angular itself.

**Edit**

I am attaching the component styles.scss file:

```
#home-section{
  // background: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2932/14143338033_20c1ce9c44_b.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  min-height:700px;

  .dark-overlay{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    min-height:700px;
  }

  .home-inner{
    padding-top:150px;
  }

  .card-form{
    opacity:0.8;
  }

  .fa{
    color:#008ed6;
    background:#fff;
    padding:4px;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you written this style anywhere in the styleCss or styleUrls css?

Comment: No, this is added by angular. If you look in the screenshots, at the bottom in the inspect, you can see these are added automatically by angular.

Comment: Can you add the CSS files from that component please?

Comment: Also please show the component code if possible

Comment: @user184994 Added the css file, thanks

Comment: Angular only adds those styles like this which are added in component's styles using styleUrls or styles property passed to it

Comment: If you could create a StackBlitz or similar that reproduces the issue, that would be very helpful. As @NanditaAroraSharma says, Angular doesn't add any CSS styling of its own

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma @user184994  Thanks. I figured out my mistake. I had added a style ` *{margin: 0%}` which was showing up as a style with name of _ngcontent on chrome inspect, so I thought it had to do with some angular style. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Told you. Angular never adds any style on its own :) Glad it got resolved